# How do I undo a Setup call for a moq Mock?

Tags: nunit, moq

This might be a special use case that I am dealing with here. Here is what my simple C# NUnit test that uses Moq looks like

```
Mock<ISomeRepository> mockR = new Mock<ISomeRepository>();
mockR.Setup(x => x.GetSomething).Returns(new Something(a=1,b=2);
--use the mocked repository here
```

Now later in this same unit test or another test case I want to invoke the real implementation of the method GetSomething() on this mockR object.
Is there a way to do that? My repository is Singleton at its heart. So even if I create a new object, the GetSomething method still returns the same Moq'd object.

Comment: 'I want to invoke the real implementation of the method GetSomething() on this mockR object'.  There is no 'real' representation of `ISomeRepository` as it's an interface.  If you have an actual implementation (say, `SomeRepository`) that you want to pass in, then create a second test method and in the setup of that method pass in the implementation rather than a mocked instance

Answer (score 1):

That would largely depend on your implementation of that `GetSomething`, which is something you're not showing here ;). Also, I'm not sure that's even a valid setup, shouldn't there be a `.Setup(..).Returns(..)` there?

Answer (score 1):

Mocks are used to represent dependencies of a class allowing that class to be tested without using their actual dependencies. Or you can do tests which involve the actual dependencies.

But using a mocked dependency and the real dependency within the *same unit test* sounds like you're not clear what your test is testing.

If it's *another test case*, it shouldn't be a problem either. Each test should not impact another, so if you set up the class under test separately that should be fine, even with a singleton.

I'm assuming that you're injecting the singleton dependency. If not, do that.